# MATLAB: Trying to not display the logical array in this code

Tags: matlab

This is a function that checks if the array that is inputted is a square matrix. The function is doing what I want, namely checking if the array is square, but it also outputs the logical array that I am using to check if the number of rows equals the number of columns.

```
function isSquare = checkSquare(x)
   [rnum, cnum] = size(x);
   isSquare = rnum == cnum;
   if isSquare == 1
       fprintf('True')
   else
       fprintf('False')
   end
end
```

Comment: just a guess (don't have a matlab copy now)... but perhaps a semicolon in your `if` statement evaluation?  `if isSquare == 1;`.  If that doesnt do the trick, can you paste some example output with a small array so users know exactly whats going on without having to run the code themselves?

Comment: oh ya, and welcome to SO!  This  is a very clear and concisely posted question for a first time poster.  Hats off to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're running the function without putting a semicolon at the end.

```matlab
>> checksquare(zeros(4,4))
True
ans = 

  logical

   1

>>
```

Instead, try this.

```matlab
>> checksquare(zeros(4,4));
True>>
```

It would be nicer for the formatting to print a newline character after `True` or `False`. Change `fprintf('True')` to `fprintf('True\n')` and `fprintf('False')` to `fprintf('False\n')` and you'll get the following result.

```matlab
>> checksquare(zeros(4,4));
True
>>
```